# Add a field to existing MongoDB document (with Mongoose in Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, updates

I have this existing document in a collection `Article` in MongoDB database:

```
[ { site: 'www.atlantico.fr',
date: '2014-05-27T11:10:19.000Z',
link: 'http://www.atlantico.fr/example.html',
_id: 538473817eb00f082f4803fc,
__v: 0} ]
```

I want to add a new field `day` with value `'example'` to this document, using Mongoose in Node.js. So I do:

```
Article.update(
      { link: 'http://www.atlantico.fr/example.html'}, 
      { $set : {day : 'example'} }, 
       function(err){  
                    });
```

But it does not work because when I query the document after that, no new field `day` appears...

I must have made a mistake when using `update` or `$set` in Mongoose, but I cannot find exactly my mistake.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Please show mongoose model for Article

Comment: At the beginning I did not have `day` field in the schema and in the model.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try

```
Article.update(
     {link: 'http://www.atlantico.fr/example.html'}, 
     {day : 'example' },
     {multi:true}, 
       function(err, numberAffected){  
       });
```

and don't forget to add day to schema.

Comment: the reminder to get it in the schema was particularly useful.

Answer (score 4):

```
await Users.updateOne( {link: 'http://www.atlantico.fr/example.html'},{ $set: { day : 'example'} }, { multi: true });
```

- update is deprecated
- use await for db operation
- if you want to add new filed in collection ,first check it is added in Model or not
  (if you don't wan't use that filed as mandatory make is as "required: false")

Answer (score 0):

```
Article.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $set: { day: 'example' }}, { new: true }, function (err, article) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  res.send(article);
});
```

I prefer this way because it's contains a callback function.

*reference and more info: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html*