# Using mongoose to add new field to existing document in mongodb through update method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update a mongodb document with mongoose in node.js

When the field exists, the update works, but if the field does not exist, the update will not work.

I want to add new fields to the document.

the MongoDB query ([$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/set/#behavior)) is working:

```
db.getCollection('users').update({ 'uid': 'uid' }, { $set: { 'vehicle_status': 'bike' } })
```

But it will not work when done in mongoose.  Using $set does not add a field.

```
User.update({ uid: uid }, { $set: { vehicle_status: vehicleSatus } }, { multi: true })
```

Comment: i found soultion.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23959287/add-a-field-to-existing-mongodb-document-with-mongoose-in-node-js?rq=1

model not defined new filed. i add new filed in model. and add filed work.

Comment: Okay, Helpful to know. Please try to spell the best you can when posting your questions here as they might be useful to many people, and it helps for them to understand them well :)

Having the field in your model is of course necessary

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
User.updateOne(
     {uid: 'uid'}, 
     {vehicle_status : 'vehicleSatus' },
     {multi:true}, 
       function(err, numberAffected){  
       });
```

Also, make sure that you add vehicle_status to the schema.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without modifying the schema?

Comment: Marwan Ossama, No you need it in the schema because the schema defines the document structure. I guess if you didn't have access to the schema, you could maybe use an existing field and store a string in the existing field possibly but that isn't a very good solution but sometimes you have no choice if you're on a closed source system or something like that.  However, in that case, the above code is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I also had the same issue. After update the schema every worked as expected. Cheers!

Comment: Also, make sure that you add vehicle_status to the schema. - important!

Comment: @TimBaker Im using mongoose v5 and it is not working. It only works if i update current fields. Do you have an idea if something has changed?

Comment: @user752746 I update the schema. After that, I have to delete all previous data to make it work again. Is there any method to add a new field without losing previous data?

Comment: @Tim if you want a new field, then why are you using update method, instead we need to use some add filed method right, also you added a vehicle status, but did yoy mention the data type? and will it cause any problem with the old recors, or the old recors value with the new filed will be null?

Answer (score 5):

Going through this solution in Year 2019.

Please note: `collection.update` is deprecated. Use `updateOne`, `updateMany`, or `bulkWrite` instead

Answer (score 4):

According to new scenario always 
use {**upsert:true**}.

upsert - if set to true and no record matched to the query, replacement object is inserted as a new record.

```
   user.updateOne(
                 { email: req.body.email },
                 { $set: { name: 'Aaakash'}},{upsert:true}).then((result, err) => {
                    return res.status(200).json({ data: result, message:"Value Updated" });
                })
```

Comment: read the question first. He asked "How to add new field in existing document" not new record

Answer (score 1):

After adding vehicle_status to the schema.

```
User.updateOne({ uid: uid }, 
               { $set: { vehicle_status: vehicleSatus  } },
               { multi: true })
  .then(() => console.log('User updated'))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```